# Main Menu Missing from Ubuntu Unity

Tags: unity, unity-dash

The Unity "main menu" in the upper left corner, which has been present for quite some time, just up and vanished. The Launcher still works, as do its menus, but the Main Menu button is gone. How do I get it back?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. It has to do with a glitch when two monitors are in use. My laptop monitor alone displays it fine, but my external monitor does not for some resolution-related reason.